# Renaming the first 10 columns in my pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm actually working with pandas Dataframes. Ihave a Dataframe with only 1 rows and 20 columns. I want to rename the first 10 columns. So i did:

```
df.columns =['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10']
```

But i get this error :

```
Length mismatch: Expected axis has 20 elements, new values have 10 elements
```

Is their any way to indicate to python that i only the first 10 columns to be rename? Or give a default name to the others ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rename` with dictionary created by `zip`, it working for any number of unique columns names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(5)])

L = ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10']
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, L)))
print (df)
   C0  C1  C2  C3  C4
0   0   1   2   3   4
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(15)])

L = ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10']
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, L)))
print (df)
   C0  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10  11  12  13  14
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
```

Comment: `df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, [f'C{i}' for i in range(11)])))` for a fancier one-liner

Answer (score 2):

Add the old columns names to fix this

```py
new_names = ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10']
df.columns = new_names + df.columns[len(new_names):]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is to assign the `new_names` to the `values` of the specific positions of `columns`

```
new_names = ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10']
df.columns.values[:len(new_names)] = new_names
```